# Passing parameter between two statefull component with react-navigation 5.x

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to pass a parameter between two statefull component (the restaurant id) in my app, the first one is my login component where i'm doing this :

```
  onPressLogin = () => {
    loginService(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then((res) => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Commandes', {id:res.data.restaurant.id})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        alert('Email/Password invalide')
      })
  }
```

And in my second component, the HomeScreen (screen: Commandes) i'm doing this :

```
componentDidMount() {
    const {id} = this.props.route.params
    this.getRestaurantInfo()
    this.getRestaurantStatus()
    this.getOrders()
    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
  }
```

But I have undefined, I have checked the doc and they only specified for stateless component...

I have also checked the value of this.props.navigation.navigate which is a function and the value of route who display this :

```
route.params Object {
  "key": "Commandes-kHfSvHgETC",
  "name": "Commandes",
  "params": undefined,
}
```

Comment: Are these components in a same stack ?

Comment: yes, they are in my stack navigator

Comment: Same stack or a different stack?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.id
```

Comment: This will not work in react-navigation v5 as params moved into the route `const { id } = route.params`
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: please make sure navigation props exist in your component   console.log(this.props.navigation)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

please check https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params out again and make sure you are doing well

Comment: I already checked the doc, in their example they only take stateless component, but for example, I need a statefull component for my Homescreen because there is multiple element who will change because of the action of the user, it must exist a solution...

Comment: there is no different way to get params in stateless and stateful components